# Kickflip animation

Tags: animation

I'm new to Blender. I'm trying to animate a kickflip. [Reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ptboO6zI5I)

If the skateboard stays horizontal no problem I can rotate it around its long axis (Y), but if I want to add a flying curve to it its make a weird rotation. I kinda understand why is it happening and why my first idea wasn't successful but unable to find out how to solve this problem.

[image]

Blend file: [skateboard.blend](https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2F1drv.ms%2Fu%2Fs!Aj8TxwIVxJknj-o54qsQ4BuBTMhbMQ%3Fe%3DNoGkDU&h=AT3l1Ury2szCxLxYAM1L3EV9lDmsyHNEZ7OaHo3rYixFSM5EAjhBtZdV1g6P5toIm-tNPJgwwhEh_DJWhhwHjil81wRtYyJ1xR7zK1GC6TyvRJMTEbsJ7h05hoDbDxB_Ty8mzA)

Comment: hello, in what way is it weird?

Comment: Moving out on the global X axis. It should only rotate around its Y axis

Comment: maybe parent it to an empty, so that you can make the skate rotate on itself and also tilt the empty the way you want?

Comment: The pivot point for the rotation is at the back. This makes the nose of the board spiral up and down in an unnatural way when the board rotates around itself and rises. Also, the up and down motion seems to be linear. It should go forward & down in a parable not in a line.

Comment: @Edgel3D I like the bounce of this "ghost rider skateboard" at the end :-)

Comment: @Blunder ,  I must have a 'thing' about bouncing.  I even do it with rope!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your animation, the pivot point for the rotation is at the back wheel of the board. This makes the nose of the board spiral up and down in an unnatural way when the board rotates around itself.

Also, the up and down motion seems to be linear. It should go forward & down in a parable, not in a linear way.

I would make a little rig then you can rotate the board around three pivot points... like so, and so, and so, and this way, and so, ...

[image: rotation test]

Just make sure you have set the bone roll values correctly. I had forgotten about it in the animation above.

The rig has a bone chain with 3 bones.

- *Back Wheel* bone, it's the root and placed from the back wheel to the front wheel
- *Front Wheel* bone, it's a child of the *Back Wheel* bone and goes from the front to the back wheel
- *Board Rotation* bone, a child of the *Front Wheel* bone but with offset (unconnected). It's placed in the center of the board.
- the skateboard object is parented to the *Board Rotation* bone. (In *Pose* mode, you need to select the skateboard object and the bone, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > *To Bone*)

In the side panel (N-panel) you can lock the location and the scale with the padlocks so you cannot accidentally move the *Board Rotation* bone.
For the *Back Wheel* and *Front Wheel* bones, you can lock the rotation around the Y-axis.

[image: skateboard rig]

Test animation
[image: example animation]

Comment: Does it seem to float a bit at the peak? It surprised me that you can make the skateboard stop, jump, and move forward again as shown in the reference video.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not really understand (yet) what I was doing with the bones, but made it work.